# Measure and perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

How can I show that every perfect set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a perfect subset of measure zero?

I have thought of a compact $K$ without isolated points, and delete sets analogous to the Cantor set.

Comment: Is this in a specific topology on a specific measure space?

Comment: The suggestion is work it in the reals set, with usual distance.

Comment: Is your goal to prove it for a more general setting?

Comment: not, as indicate the suggestion.

Comment: Let $S$ be perfect. Assume $S$ is nowhere-dense, else the problem is easy. Take $a,b\in \mathbb R$  such that  $T=S\cap [a,b]$ is perfect. Let $[a,b] \ T=\cup_nI_n$  where the $I_n$ are pair-wise disjoint open intervals.  We can carefully remove another sequence of  open intervals from  $[a,b],$ leaving a perfect subset of $T$ of measure $ 0.$..... Begin  by removing $A=(x,y)$ with $x,y\in T$, where $\sup I_1<x<y<b$  and $x=\sup (T\cap [a,x))$ and $y=\inf (T\cap (y,b])$ and  such that $y-x\geq (b-\sup I_1)/3.$ ... I will leave the rest to "the reader".

Comment: are $I_n$ without condition, only pairwise disjoint? what is the notation [a,b]T?